# SandBox Webpart embedded inside Masterpage in SharePoint 2013 giving error

Tags: sharepoint, master-pages, sandbox, sharepoint-2013

Well, SharePoint 2013 is not very Sandbox friendly.  Having lots of issues.

In SharePoint 2010, I was able to successfully embed Sandbox webparts inside the masterpage using this:

```
<WebPartPages:SPUserCodeWebPart runat="server" Description="Description" Title="TITLE"
    AssemblyFullName="$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$" SolutionId="00000000-0000-0000-0000-00000000000"
    ID="ID" TypeFullName="Namespace.WP">
</WebPartPages:SPUserCodeWebPart>
```

However, when I add this inside a masterpage in SharePoint 2013, I get the following error:

> ExecuteRequestInSandBox call failed. System.NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(PersonalizationScope scope, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags, BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.BinaryWebPartSerializer.Serialize(SerializationMode mode, BinaryWebPartSerializerFlag binaryWebPartSerializerFlags, BinaryWebPartSerializerWriter writer)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPUserCodeWebPart.EnsurePersistedBlobsMatchPropertiesCollection()     at Microsoft.SharePoint.WebPartPages.SPUserCodeWebPart.GetWebPartDataForRemoteCall(Object& viewState, Object& controlState)     at Microsoft.SharePoint.UserCode.SPUserCodeWebPartRemoteExecutionHelper.ExecuteRequestInSandBox(HttpContext context, SPWeb web, SPWebPartManager manager, SPUserCodeWebPart userCodeWebPart)

Comment: I have the same issue, if you have found a solution, could you please share?

Comment: You can refer to my answer.  I'm keeping this question open, maybe someone will figure this out.

Comment: I am trying to debug this now.  I'm reverse-engineering the assembly.  The NRE is thrown by this line: `SPAttachedProperty propertyData = this.AttachedProperties.Get(this.m_webPart, pair2.Key + "Resource");`  m_attachedProperties is null, because BinaryWebPartSerializer is passed a `null` `SPWebPartManager` and the web part has personalizable properties.  I'm going to see what I can do solve either part of that..

Comment: There are seemingly 22 personalizable properties even without adding any.  So the problem is the web part doesn't have a web part manager.  Adding one to the master page gives an error that one already exists... not sure what's next..?

Comment: Update, SetWebPartManager should set it on the web part, from WebPartManager.OnPageInitComplete (all internal/hidden methods).  Debugging that now to see why that doesn't happen.

Comment: So _personalizationState is null on the WebPartManager.  To be continued..

Comment: Changing the WebPartPages namespace (Register directive) to use version 16 rather than 15.. seems to work on the latest SP2013/O365 tenant (not tested thoroughly).  But then I can't debug anything using that master page locally..

Comment: Good job in figuring this out.  My company did not want to invest more time into this, so for now we are just using farm level solutions, but gradually we will move on to the app model, as that is recommended by MSFT.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this (hurrah!) by changing the version of referenced assemblies to 16.0.0.0 from 15.0.0.0 (or rather, removing the version and key parts of the assembly names altogether) in the Register tags.

Basically I think there's a bug in wave 15, fixed in wave 16.

Only problem is, my dev environment is wave 15 (as is everyone else's I presume).  But removing the version number from the reference tags, it at least won't crash-out completely, just give an error message where the web part would appear.

Comment: I just ended up ditching SandBox altogether.  It seems MSFT is deprecating that, and pushing more for the app model.  For now, I am just using Farm-Level solutions, but I'll probably go to the app model as well, once it matures.

Comment: Sandbox is my only option.  I'm on SP online (so no farm) and the app model is terrible.  After weeks of the team trying to use the app model, it was pain pain pain pain pain.

Comment: I agree, App Model is pain...that is why I'm waiting for it to mature...Well, in that case I'm glad you figured it out. =)

Comment: This is an old post and answer, but if you update the SP 2013 farm to at least version 15.0.4569 (Service Pack 1), then you should not run into this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried a bunch of things, and it seems that you cannot embed a sandbox webpart onto a masterpage.  However, a farm level webpart solution can be successfully embedded into a masterpage.

I have no idea why this is the behavior.  You can, however, deploy an application page with SandBox WP embedded on it, and the application page will work fine.  This is very interesting behaviour.

For now, I'm keeping this question open.  Maybe someone will figure out this craziness.

The only bad thing is that you cannot deploy your masterpage to SharePoint Online (Hosted) because it does not allow farm-level solutions.  Maybe AppParts, or iFrames, or embedded javascript/jQuery with a back-end fake service might do the trick, but for my purpose, I was looking at a bit more complexity.

Comment: This is an old post and answer, but if you update the SP 2013 farm to at least version 15.0.4569 (Service Pack 1), then you should not run into this issue with the sandbox control in the OP.

Answer (score 1):

Ran into a similar issue today on on SP farm. After installing SharePoint 2013 SP1, this is fixed. If you are experiencing this, check your patch version. If it is less than 15.0.4569, upgrade to at least 15.0.4569.